# Validação em PHP de formulário no Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, formulário

Estou montando um formulário em WordPress e preciso validar dados bancários, CPF, Número do Banco, Agência entre outros, e utilizo o plugin Contact Form 7. Minha dúvida é como faço para validar por PHP os campos digitados pelo usuário neste plugin. A [documentação](http://contactform7.com/docs/) e o [FAQ](http://contactform7.com/faq/) do plugin não explicam como fazer isso. Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Answer (score 3):

Não é exatamente simples... É necessário criar um outro plugin para cuidar da validação. O primeiro a fazer é saber quais campos quer filtrar:

<kbd>[image: configuração do cf7]</kbd>

Digamos que seja nos campos de tipo `email*`, então o filtro vai ser `wpcf7_validate_email*` e a mensagem de erro vai ser conectada ao nome do campo `your-email`.

Se o site tem mais de um formulário com campos do tipo `email*` é possivel validar cada formulário filtrando através do ID do formulário, que é usado no shortcode: `[contact-form-7 id="2919" title="aaa"]`.

O código do plugin seria:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Validar forms do CF7
 * Plugin URI:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31028/201
 * Author:      brasofilo 
 */

/**
 * Evita ativar o plugin se o CF7 não estiver ativo
 */
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activation_sopt_31022' );
function activation_sopt_31022()
{
    $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
    check_admin_referer( "activate-plugin_{$plugin}" ); 
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WPCF7_Submission') )
        wp_die( 'O Contact Form 7 não está ativo' );
}

add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'check_form_so_31022' );

/**
 * Iniciar a checagem dos forms enviados
 */
function check_form_so_31022( $data )
{
    # Conferir ID de um form específico
    if( $data['_wpcf7'] !== '2919' )
        return;

    # Validar campo de email
    if( !validate_email_so_31022( $data['your-email'] ) )
        add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'erro_email_so_31022', 10, 2 );

    # Validar campo de texto
    if( !validate_text_so_31022( $data['your-subject'] ) )
        add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'erro_text_so_31022', 10, 2 );

    return $data;
}

/**
 * TODO: Função personalizada para validar texto
 */
function validate_text_so_31022( $text )
{
    # FAÇA AQUI SUA VALIDAÇÃO e retorne true ou false
    return false;
}

/**
 * Filtro específico para mostrar erro em campo de texto
 */
function erro_text_so_31022( $result, $tag )
{
    $result['valid'] = false;
    $result['reason']['your-subject'] = 'Erro';
    return $result;

}

/**
 * TODO: Função personalizada para validar email
 */
function validate_email_so_31022( $email )
{
    # FAÇA AQUI SUA VALIDAÇÃO e retorne true ou false
    return false;
}

/**
 * Filtro específico para mostrar erro em campo de email
 */
function erro_email_so_31022( $result, $tag )
{
    $result['valid'] = false;
    $result['reason']['your-email'] = 'Logical Error: Check in date should be before check out date';
    return $result;

}
```

O resultado ao tentar enviar o formulário (com AJAX ligado) é:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

Tem um [plugin para validação do CF7 com jQuery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/), mas não sei como funciona. E lembrando que é só desligar o JS no browser pra sobrepassar esse tipo de validação. Vide [*Can I validate only with jQuery or do I need PHP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23922284/1287812)